# Feynman's trick of integration problem $e^{-x^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have being trying some hard integration problems and I can not find a way to get this, as said in the title, this integral should be donde using Differentiating under the integral sign. I know there are other methods but since the chapter is about this technique, I would appreciate if it is solve using it.

The problem is:

$$\text{Prove that} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{-x^2}dx}=\sqrt{\pi}\quad \text{Hint: Let} f(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{\frac{e^{-\alpha^2(1+x^2)}}{1+x^2}dx}$$

I tried, because of the fact that the integral is symmetric around $0$ that:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{e^{-x^2}dx}=2\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-x^2}dx}$$

Also, by differentiating $f(\alpha)$, I got:

$$f'(\alpha)=\int_{0}^{\infty}{-2\alpha e^{-a^2(1+x^2)}dx}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}{-2\alpha e^{-a^2(1+x^2)}dx}=-2\alpha e^{-\alpha^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-\alpha^2 x^2}dx}$$

I do not know how to relate both expression, I am stuck at this point, if you could help me continue I would appreciate it

Comment: what about the second derivative

Comment: I do not see how differentiating again would make the problem any easier, could you show me?

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $y=\alpha x$ in the last integral?

Comment: I tried and this led me to $-2e^{-a^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{e^{-y^2}dy}$ but that just gets me to the initial problem...

Comment: I am curious as to why this method is used, since it is very easy to show that $I^2=\pi$.

Comment: Because sometimes it is easier to do it using Feynman's trick rather than any other integration technique, it is some times only possible to do it trought the trick. In this case, we must use it simply because the chapter is about the method itself and the writer want us to practice it

Answer (score 4):

Continuing from your last step and denoting

$$2I:=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$$

we have that

$$f'(\alpha)=-2\alpha e^{-\alpha^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-\alpha^2x^2}dx=-2Ie^{-\alpha^2}$$

We note that $f(0)=\pi/2$. We integrate both sides in $[0,t]$ and we get

$$f(t)-f(0)=-2I\int_{0}^{t}e^{-\alpha^2}d\alpha$$

Lastly, taking $t\to\infty$ and noting that $f(\infty)=0$ we obtain the result we wanted:

$$f(0)=2I^2\iff 2I=\sqrt{2f(0)}=\sqrt{\pi}$$

To justify that $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=0$ we only need to perform a change of variables in the original integral $y=t x$:

$$|f(t)|=|t|e^{-t^2}\int_{0}^{\infty}dy\frac{e^{-y^2}}{y^2+t^2}\leq\frac{e^{-t^2}}{|t|}I$$

and since $I$ can be shown to be finite very easily, taking limits above yields $f(\infty)=0$.